# Having Trouble Getting A JS Slider to Connect with Data for Filtering

Tags: javascript, filter, slider, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

I am working from mapbox gl js starter code (link below) and modifying the code to fit my data. I have been successful in getting my local file "resi.geojson" data to show on the map, however I am unable to get the "slider" functionality connected. Can someone help me understand why it the slider is not connecting? Both the "label" the actual slider are not working and i believe it may not be matching in the Filter.

The example is using "month" to filter and i am trying to filter my data by the "year" property

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/timeline-animation/

I am using chrome and building the app in ruby on rails, and localhost server. The only error the console is giving me is "GET http://localhost:3000/jquery.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)" and there is no further info. I have looked all over on mapbox gl js API and also online and struggling to connect the dots

//html below for slider

```
<label id='year'></label>
<input id='slider' type='range' min='2000' max='2005' step='1' value='2000'/>
```

//goal is to filter data by years

```
var years = [
  2001,
  2002,
  etc
];
```

//create function to filter by year. 'residential-circles' is the name of the mapbox data object that pulls in the data and applies styles

```
function filterBy(year) {

var filter = ['<=', 'year', year];
map.setFilter('residential-circles', filter);
```

// Set slider label to the year

```
document.getElementById('year').textContent = years[year];
```

// Create a year property value based on time used to filter against.

```
data.features = data.features.map(function(d) {
  d.properties.year = new Date(d.properties.year);
  return d;
});
```

//above used to grab data from resi.geojson data structured below:

```
{
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "Status": "Complete",
        "Project": "123 Fake Street",
        "Year": 2018,
      },
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          -87.61961,
          41.890696
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      },
      "id": "00f64f2be217aa192cded76188dece01"
    },
```

// some irrelevant mapbox gl js code to map.addSource and map.addLayer the resi.geojson to style the underlying data.

//execute filter using slider UI

```
filterBy(2000);

document.getElementById('slider').addEventListener('input', function(e) {var year = parseInt(e.target.value, 10);
 filterBy(year);
 });
```

I am expecting to be able to use the slider as in the mapbox example provided, but nothing is happening when i move the slider handle and the console is not telling me anything to help me troubleshoot on my own

When i break the filter using an incorrect name as the key, for example, 'resi-circles' all the information is displaying, meaning the filter probably is not working/eliminating any of the data so the function is allowing me to see the entire set of the styled data

```
map.setFilter('resi-circles', filter);
```

When i put in the correct name as the key as below, all the styling and data disappears from the map, which leads me to believe the filter is maybe being activated but the 'year' data is somehow not passing through correctly and thus the boolean is evaluating to 'false' for all my data. Just a guess.

```
map.setFilter('residential-circles', filter);
```

Thanks so much for any pointers or assistance you can give me towards a solution!!

Answer (score 0):

figured it out, was more of a mapbox issue. updated filter as below, and 'Year' from geojson is case sensitive 'Y'

var filter = ['<=',['number',['get','Year']], year];

mapbox code required 'number' line below to grab the .geojson data

'circle-color': [
    'interpolate',
        ['linear'],
        ['number',['get', 'Units']],
          1, '#FCA107',
          600, '#7F3121'
        ],

This example also is implementing a similar slider functionality and was helpful for cross reference

https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/show-changes-over-time/